# Android emulator not installed app

Tags: android

Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error). In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.tell_it_dell.myapplication1"
>   pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.tell_it_dell.myapplication1
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
>
> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.tell_it_dell.myapplication1
>   DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think...reCreate this Virtual device.

Answer (score 2):

What I did to fix it, is to open gradlew via cmd, and write "gradlew clean" on the project. Then pressed play button and it worked again.

Comment: How did you do this? Please describe the steps. I always get `gradlew command not found`.

Comment: @Shubham add a dot and a slash before gradlew as `./gradlew clean`

Comment: The problem is resolved by disabling Instant Run in `AS 2.0 Preview 3b`.

Somehow having it turned on, keeps producing INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT when installing any app, even if it's actually not on the device.