# APK Installation error in device

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting error while installing apk via android studio.

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
    Error while Installing APK
```

i tried **build:clean**
also restart device.. 
error not resolves.

Comment: try to uninstall the application, and remove/delete some data from your device.

Comment: You creating signed apk or is this debug apk?

Comment: installing debug apk

Comment: @janki okay, try to clean your project and check it. If not solved then free some space from your device and then check.

Comment: @janki which solution works? cleaning or free some space?

Comment: free some space from sd card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110594/discussion-between-pratt-and-janki).

Comment: I think its helpful to you.
Read this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50598079/7048363

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Disabling Instant run fixed it for me

Go to Preferences>Builld,Execution, Deployment> Instant Run

Then unmark Enable instant Run to hot swap code ...

[Sorce from the comments in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500958/6531461)

And also don't forget to report the issue to google to be fixed faster.

Comment: This worked for me. Show be marked as the correct answer. There seems to be some bug in Android Studio.

Answer (score 15):

I have solved this problem by turning off MIUI optimization.

For this go to `setting`-> `developerOptions`-> `MIUI Optiomization`.

**Update:**
Apart from above solution. If you are using Android studio version 3.0 or 3+ then we can not directly use the apk after running on the device from the build->output->apk folder.

instead we need to build apk as stated below.(this is not a signed apk)

go to **Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)** then copy the apk from build -> output -> apk -> debug

and then you are good to go.

Comment: That's the only thing that worked for my Xiaomi device

Comment: Worked for me too, using Xiaomi device. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one answer to this problem, **Disable Instant Run**. I also faced the same issue and resolved by disabling instant run. Below are steps to disable Instant Run on latest version of Android Studio(3.1.2):

1. Go to Android Studio Settings
2. Search *Instant Run* in search box in top left of Android Studio Setting Window OR Click on **Build, Execution, Deployment**
3. Here you will find Instant Run
4. By default it is Enabled, uncheck **Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy(default enabled)**
5. Click **OK** button at the bottom
6. Restart your Android Studio and try to install `apk` again

To know more about Instant Run, check official documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/?utm_source=android-studio#instant-run

Here is one old YouTube video as well about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuerGSylc9A

Answer (score 3):

There are various issue which can leads to error “App not installed error” and to fix that we need to identify the reason for that. Read out the reasons written here.

**Reason for “App not installed error” in android phone**

**Dimmer Application** – Any dimmer app is running in your android phone then Install button will not work while installing app in your phone

**Low storage** – Android software and if data such as photos, videos, music, messages, Apps, contacts, emails, etc are stored in the internal memory there is not adequate storage left for another App, leading to Android App not installed error.

**Corrupted App file** – When you don’t download Apps from the Play Store and choose another platform to do that, Those App files are mostly corrupt and cannot installed on your device. I personally recommend you not to download apk from other sources / website

**SD Card not mounted** – When your phone is connected to your PC device which can access the SD Card from your device. In that situations if you install an App and choose to save it to your SD Card, you will see Android App not installed error because the App cannot find the SD card as it is not mounted in your device.

**App compatibility with Android Version** – Some applications on the internet which are only meant to work on some Android versions. Installing these applications on newer android versions will show error.

**Application Permission** – Application running in the background and App Permission are not new concepts. Such errors can also cause the Unknown Error Code during App installation.

**Incorrect file** – If you already have an App installed but download another variant with distinct signed or unsigned certificate can also show an error.

Methods to Fix App Not Installed Error | App not installed error solution

**Method 1: Allow Apps from Unknown Sources**

In android phone to install app which is not downloaded from Playstore you need to tick Install app from unknown source. By default this option is untick fro safety purpose, so if this is untick you will not be also to install app in android phone and will give you Application not installed in android smartphone. So to fix this follow the below path.

Go to Settings → Security → Unknown Sources. Enable Unknown Sources.
Now try to install App.

**Method 2: Clear Data and Cache of Package Installer**

1. Firstly Open setting of your Android device.
2. Tap on the option called Apps or Manage apps
3. Check for the Package Installer App under system Apps
4. You will find two option of Clear data and Clear cache. (Android Marshmallow 6.0 users check for option Storage to clear data and cache)
5. Clear the data and cache and you problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to cleaning your project and then check it. If it will not solved still then try to free some space from your device, because this error may occur due to lake of space in device memory. Please check with these both ways.

Comment: Sometimes it occurs because of already installed app in your phone, I have resolved it by manually uninstalling the app from device then re-building from Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

May be Only Disabling the instant run is the right solution. Uninstalling android studio or creating new virtual device will not solve the problem.

Setting--> expand (Build,Execution,deployment) ----> Instant Run (Please Uncheck the Enable Instant run to hot swap code option )

Answer (score 1):

You might need to enable running app from unknown sources in phone.
There are different ways to turn it ON depend on the mobile manufacturer.

To allow app installs follow this steps in Android device:

1. Navigate to Setting > Security.
2. Check the option "Unknown sources".
3. Tap OK on the prompt message then Select "Trust".

Also in few devices, once you run your code you need to provide run time permission to allow running the App. Just Click on Allow in dialog, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This Error occur main reason is **Instant run**.

> When you will using instant run only the updated part gets replaced on device.
>   Some times the application seems to not updating and it is staying at
>   previous build.

**Solution:**

You have to `disable Instant Run` to generate the whole APK file is updated on device.

In Android Studio:

```
File -> Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run:
Uncheck : (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code....) > Apply.
```

Thanks.

Comment: In my case i am not using instant run

Answer (score 0):

Android studio change the concept of Building APK

Go to Build section in android studio,

Build apk

now install this apk