# DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing APK

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

[image]I am using **Android Studio 2.2** Preview. I am facing the issue

> Failure: Install failed invalid apk
>
> Error: While installing apk,

I have made changes in build.gradle but could not retrack it, please suggest me solution???

Comment: uninstall existing version from device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application will not run on device: DELETE\_FAILED\_INTERNAL\_ERROR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010388/application-will-not-run-on-device-delete-failed-internal-error)

Comment: Done, but could not successful. @ZeeshanKhan

Comment: Please include adb log (Android monitor log) of the error that happens when you try to install.

Comment: are you trying in genymotion or any other such emulator. if yes try deleting the emulator and re creating the same

Comment: wow this problem is still exist in android studio 3.0.1

Comment: Instead of disabling instant run you can do:
Build-> Clean Project

Comment: Just select Build-> Clean Project and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

**Android studio mac/windows/linux:**

**Steps in together (mac):**
Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run

**Steps in together (windows & linux):** File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run

**Steps in Detail :**

**Steps 1:** Studio > Preferences (for windows & linux got to File > settings > Build, Execution, Deployment and then same as mac)

[image]

**Steps 2:** *Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment*

[image]

**Steps 3:** *Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run*

[image]

**Steps 4:** *Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run*

[image]

Comment: Disabling instant run worked on Windows too, with Xiami Redmi 4 Pro

Comment: Confirmed working on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 with Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: Can someone explain why this works, if one does uncheck instant run

Comment: With my Asus was because Android prevent crashes if you have multiple users in your smartphone. I've got 2 users Owner and Guest ( for when I planning to give the smartphone to my "terminator" niece!!!!).

Comment: Rebuild the project worked for me. Didn't wanted to disable instant run. Thanks, @h4sn

Comment: Hmm.. sadly doesn't work for me on Android Studio 3.4, Debian Linux 9.9 :-/

Comment: Thanks. Was getting crazy not knowing what was wrong, couldn't run the app after changing the sdkVersion. It worked for me

Answer (score 258):

In Android Studio 2.3

Disable Instant Run

Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Instant Run

[Source: comment by @Shubham A.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500958)

**Edit: To Disable Instant run**

*In Windows:*

1. Open Find Action: `Control + Shift + A`.
2. Search `instant run` and open `instant run` under `settings`.
3. Uncheck `Enable instant run...`

*In Mac:* I don't have a mac, so try like

1. Open Find Action: `Command + Shift + A`.
2. Search `instant run` and open `instant run` under `settings`.
3. Uncheck `Enable instant run...`

Comment: I had the same problem and I was getting the same error, even if the application doesn't exists in emulator (brand new emulator). Disabling Instant Run resolved in Android Studio 2.3. Thumbs up for you!

Comment: what if you want to use Instant Run?

Comment: restarting the emulator made it work for me after disabling.

Comment: Disabling the instant run worked for me as well, much appreciated!

Comment: If you get an error after disabling Instant Run, then you can solve it by setting multiDexEnabled true in gradle defaultConfig

Comment: Didin't help me in AS 2.3.1.

Comment: working well on android studio 2.3.3 and xiaomi redmi 4A

Comment: and when we can enable back?

Answer (score 38):

This worked for my xiaomi redmii note 4
after allowing developer options and allowing USB debugging
go to settings-> developer options-> uncheck Turn on MIUI optimization
Restart your device and now install the app.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: You saved my life : ))

Answer (score 21):

For Android Studio on Mac :

Navigation Bar :

Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run >
Uncheck : Enable Instant Run

For Android Studio on Windows :

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run >
Uncheck : Enable Instant Run

Comment: Disabling instant run works. Seems a big issue with instant run feature.

Answer (score 19):

```js
 Disable Instant Run. Steps in Android Studio

Goto

 1. File -> setting(or CLRT+ALT+S)
 2. Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run 
 3. Disable Instant Run
```

**step by step (windows)**

**step 1** : Go to file -> settings

[image]

**step 2** : Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

[image]

**step 3** : disable the instant values

[image]

**step 4** : finally disable the **Instant Run**

[image]

Answer (score 13):

For Xiaomi mobile

```
1.Setting=>About phone=>tap 7 times on MIUI version


2.Setting=>Developer options=> Developer options (ON)

                            => USB Debugging (ON)

                            => Install via USB(ON)
```

Install via USB

if

> enable to ON then

*Disable WiFi and switch install via USB on while you are connected through mobile data and under your xiaomi account. It works!*

Answer (score 9):

Go to

File->settings->Buil,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run->Disable it.

//now you are good to go.

Comment: Why do you think that the Instant Run is the problem?

Comment: @yakobom Refer this link :- https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run , most of us don't have gradle configured for instatnt run so it shows the error. It is better to turn off the instant run and Instant Run requires API 21 or higher.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered a similar problem, I moved the project directory, resulting in installation failure, my solution is as follows:
Build->ReBuild

Answer (score 7):

Oh my goodness, after a long time I have resolved the issue by changing the ApplicationID: "*com.company.2016app*" to "***com.company.app***" in build.grade. It resolved all my issues. Now its working great.

Comment: You just saved my life and my job. THank you!

Answer (score 7):

In my case clean project and rebuild works, no need to disable instant run and restart.

Answer (score 5):

In lollipop and above versions Android introduced multiple users, When you delete an app it still exists in device. Please make sure your app is deleted from all users and then reinstall it.

You can check by going to Settings->Apps->All and check your app in the list, On selecting your app tap on more button in actionbar and select uninstall for all users.

Answer (score 5):

Below solution worked for my Xiaomi mobile phone:

Go to Settings -> Additional settings -> Developer options
and check **Install via USB**,
if toast **The device is temporarily restricted** shown, please turn your WI-FI off, turn on mobile data. Then try it again.

If A.S. Instance Run is still not work when you finished all steps above, perhaps you turned on MIUI optimization, please follow below step and try again:

Settings -> Additional settings -> Developer options
and uncheck **Turn on MIUI optimization**

Answer (score 5):

Different solutions for the same problem:

> **1. uncheck the Instant Run**

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

> **2. Restart Android Studio**

Click on File> invalidate Caches/Restart, then click on **Invalidate and 
Restart** button from the pop up window.

> **3. Check Device's memory**

Sometimes your device don't have enough space to install new applications, in that case android studio through this error.

> **4. Check manifest for Activities Declaration**

Make sure that your manifest.java have declared all of the used activities properly.

Hope it would help :)

Answer (score 5):

**Android Install on Device Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]
**Redmi Note 3**

Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if it's listed.

Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown Sources option.

Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.

Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options:Enable view attribute inspection

Finally Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options:Turn off MIUI optimization.

**NOTE** - Signin in to MI account is required to enable Install via USB option.

Ref: http://en.miui.com/thread-410773-1-1.html

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem, I tried the solution to disable the instant run, but you can not use the instant run, which for me is harmful, because it is an extremely useful tool.

I found another solution, which is to delete the "build" folder and re-run the project, and the error disappears, the app is executed and I can use the instant run.

[image: Delete this folder]

Comment: this effective solution, and also made me make use of the instant run and not to lose it

Answer (score 3):

If your device is a Xiaomi

1. Enable OEM unlocking
2. Disable Verify apps over USB

[image: My Screenshoot]

Comment: for me, with a Xiaomi Redmi note 4X

the option I needed to enable to fix the issue was "Install via USB"

Answer (score 2):

If your device is a Xiaomi the answer is:

Go to settings > installed apps > on the top choose "ALL" > go to the bottom find "Documents" app (its in bottom because disabled) > **enable** it with pressing enable on the bottom screen...

edit: I was used Android Studio 2.3 at the time

Comment: My device is Xiaomi but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: damm, it solved for me on Android 2.3 try to disable Instant run.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Go to File> invalidate Caches/Restart
then click on Invalidate and Restart button from the pop up.
Now, try running your project.

Answer (score 2):

You need rebuild the project

If using Android Studio 2.3:

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Even if after that your app start with a error just rebuild the project again:

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Answer (score 2):

In Device Developer option

Check Install Via USB is ON compulsory.

Comment: repeating in away another answer

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in my xiaomi note 4a device. I solved it by turning off MIUI optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem. If you want install your application using USB. You have to check the (Install Via USB option in Redimi note4). Hope this will be helpful to someone.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If Emulator is opened, please close it.

And Restart the android studio.It worked for me.

Give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run any android app on a phone for **the first time**, make sure that you don't forget to set the **Install via USB** option. Otherwise the above error will be reported.

Answer (score 0):

When i try create another `package` under the `Java folder` this error will happen

But When i moved this special package under the `main package` of my project , everything will be ok .

I'm testing on real android device .(Sumsung J2)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by:

1. go to sdk folder/platform-tools by cmd ,type adb shell
2. delete all the .apk files of your project from ../output-folder
3. restart your emulator
4. run your project.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes with **Android Studio lower than 2.4** when you try to enable **Java 8 features** in gradle settings following the [instruction](http://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html). Error can be reproduced in a new project with those gradle settings.

A higher version is needed, or a [preview one](http://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for my specific case:**

Maybe it has happened because you have installed your apk first by the Google Play (my apk was running OK until I found an error) and then trying to reinstall it from your Android Studio (in order to figure it out), I have a solution:

Go to your phone/tablet. Settings -> Backup & Reset -> **Disable Automatic Restore**

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Even after following all the suggestions, if it shows error then check your buildType in Gradle. 
Make sure 
signingConfig signingConfigs.config

is in **release scope, not in debug**.

Answer (score 0):

Check `</provider>` that have been added recently to the `manifest`

Something like `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`

Also check `authorities` of the `</provider>` if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same Error in MI Note 4 
I solved my problem :-
Enable Install via USB in Developer Option.
Developer Option>>Install Via USB
To enable Install Via USB Turn off WiFi And Turn On Network Data and try to Enable

Answer (score 0):

I just updated minSdkVersion to 17 and sync. And then I solved that problem.

in the build.gradle(Module:app), Change like below.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 17
    ...
}
```