# application installation failed error at runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I receive the following error every time I try and run my application
[image: Android Error]

I tried all the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892270/delete-failed-internal-error-error-while-installing-apk) and none of them worked.

The weird thing here is that, I tried to run my application for the first time of the Android Emulator and I got the same error. I never installed the application there, yet I get the same error.

any ideas what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the followings:

*Clean up your Project(Build/Clean Project)

*Uninstall any previous installations of your application on device(if it is present)

*Restart Android studio

*Restart Android Emulator

If your problem is still there, then try to restart your system