# When i trying to test my android application, it shows the installation has failed. I don't know what is the reason

Tags: android, installation

**I have took this project from my personal pc and installed in my friend pc. So sdk path is different. Is that the reason?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project

**Build > Clean Project**

OR

**Disable instant run.**

Go into **Settings(Win 10)** or **Preferences(Mac)**, then select Build, Execution, and Development, choose Instant Run then disable it.

About **SDK** Path thing, based on my experience, Android Studio usually solved **SDK** Path difference problem itself automatically.

Comment: I'm getting this                                                                         
                     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe''

Answer (score 0):

If your version Android Studio is 2.3

Disable Instant Run in :
Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Instant Run

This option does not exist in  my Android Studio 1.4 
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892270/delete-failed-internal-error-error-while-installing-apk)

Answer (score 0):

**Disable instant run.**

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Development -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run to Hot Swap Code/Resource changes on Deploy (Default Enabled)
```

**And then Rebuild your Project**

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe''