# DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing APKs

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting this error message:

> "DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

while Installing APKs, I even wiped data from emulator and also tried choosing another device yet the error persists. Please help me out.
I have tried disabling instant Run but doesn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892270/delete-failed-internal-error-error-while-installing-apk ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes I did but that didn't worked for me.

Comment: try restart and see ...

Comment: I actually copied and pasted previous project then run it but I changed package name. Is it the source of problem?

Comment: Not sure but you can try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DELETE\_FAILED\_INTERNAL\_ERROR Error while Installing APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892270/delete-failed-internal-error-error-while-installing-apk)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (in Idea) that was caused by FLAG_TEST_ONLY (read [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html)).

Try disabling **Instant Run** and then adding **"-t"** flag to Install Flags in your Run Configuration:

[image: Run Config]