# Android : Unable to install app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am unable to install my app on my Lenovo Phab PLUS (Lenovo PB-1 770M, Android 5.1.1 API 22) through either Android Studio or by copying the APK manually.

1. **Through Android Studio**: I get the error "Failure to install APK [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]". It suggests me that there might be an existing app on the phone with the same package with stale dexed jars and prompts me to uninstall the existing app. However, when I proceed with "yes", it simply fails and throws the error "Error installing APK". I have attached the screenshots here.

[image]
[image]

2. **Manually installing APK**: It tries to install the app but shows up a screen saying "APK not installed".

[image]

The problem is, my app is **not listed in the Settings->apps directory** on the phone. So I have no way to figure out if there is an existing app with the same package name on the phone. Since I cannot see it, I cannot uninstall it manually, hence I cannot install anything with the same package name again.
Can anyone help with this?

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: does your phone have multiple user accounts? if yes switch to another account and uninstall app from that account

Comment: No, only one account.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43734320/3967525 see if it helps.@Raymond232

Comment: @Soham, I have Instant Run disabled already.

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio
select Build-> Build APK(s).
Try to install new build generated by this step.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command prompt, navigate to your Android SDK/platform-tools folder, 
use the following command.

**adb uninstall yourpackagename**

Comment: It gave this error Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

I have some solutions try these.. hope any one  will be work for you..
1) Go to -- File => "Invalidate Cache\ Restart" and then run the app..
2)Go to Build -> clean Project then run App
if above both not worked then 
3) delete ".gradle folder" inside your project then restart android studio and run

Answer (score 0):

This problem can arise based on a lot of reasons. One of my friend had the same issue and when I tried fixes with him, following are the steps we followed:

1. Clear cache of your project **File -> Invalidate cache/restart**
2. Restart your emulator or try to create new and delete the existing one.
   And then the problem was far gone.

I know this is not the exact fix for you, because your problem can't be anticipated so easily, but I just wanted to share with you, hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Android Studio project with the same Package name.

Install the new Project with the same package name.
Install now the original app.