# When I start my app on an emulator there is always an old apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried different solutions but I can't discover why it does that. Look at the image [Problem].

[image]

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the old APK from the device?

Comment: Try disabling instant run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892270/delete-failed-internal-error-error-while-installing-apk

Comment: Yes @MichaelDodd, I uninstalled it.

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try rebuilding your project open the build menu **Build->Build project** and after build is complete. Run the project again.

Comment: Is there any special message showing in the log? if not try the proposition of @MichaelDodd to uninstall app and then run

Comment: It shows "Couldn't load memtrack module", it can be a problem?

Comment: You can find here about "memotrack module" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a new emulator with higher API.

Comment: It can be due to some hardware problem. Just quickly check in the AVD manager by editing your AVD that the Graphics is set to Software.

Comment: The problem appears also if I use a physical device. I don't think AVD is a problem.