# How to solve Error while Installing APKs on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-install-apk

When I try to run my app in Emulator its installation failed, It shows a popup for Uninstall application like,

[image]

Once I press **OK** button, it shows installing and after some times it shows install failed , here is the log,

```
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs
```

On my studio Instant Run is already Enabled,
Steps : File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run >

After disable `Instant Run` I got another error as,

```
06/19 16:26:53: Launching app
Install failed.
Installation failed
<a href='rerun'>Rerun</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

open terminal in android studio and write this command

adb uninstall your_package_name

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, uninstalling the app in the emulator solved the stuff. 
Otherwise you can read this answer about this kind of problems: [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR Error while Installing APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892270/delete-failed-internal-error-error-while-installing-apk)